# CSS Footer Layout Problem

Tags: css, layout, footer

Am trying to create a cross-browser 3 column footer that are equal in width to each other, but doesn't go beyond the main body width of 900px. This code isn't doing it??

```
html
<div id="footer">
    <p class="left">About<br />Contact<br />Next line here</p>
    <p class="right"> does not evaluate or guarantee the accuracy</p>
<p class="centered">Terms<br />Privacy<br />Disclaimer</p>
</div>

css
 #footer  {
  color: #ffffff;
  width:100%;
  background: #111;
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;   
   } 

.left {
text-align:left;
float:left;
}

.right{
float:right;
text-align:right;
}

.centered{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can see, with your current mark-up, is:

```
#footer {
    width: 900px;
}
#footer > p {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

p:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/W5fmf/).

---

**Edited** to suggest a slight revision, as your footer `div` appears to be a list of links to other content, I'd suggest amending your mark-up, with the following as a suggested guide:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li>menu one
            <ul>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Next line here</li>
            </ul></li>
        <li>menu two
            <ul>
                <li>Does not evaluate, or guarantee the accuracy</li>
            </ul></li>
        <li>menu three
            <ul>
                <li>Terms</li>
                <li>Privacy</li>
                <li>Disclaimer</li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#footer {
    width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer > ul {
    width: 100%;
}

#footer > ul > li {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#footer > ul > li > ul {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/W5fmf/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="left">About<br />Contact<br />Next line here</div>
    <div class="right"> does not evaluate or guarantee the accuracy</div>
<div class="centered">Terms<br />Privacy<br />Disclaimer</div>
</div>
```

for your htmll, and this for your styles:

```
#footer  {
  color: #ffffff;
  width:100%;
  background: #111;
 overflow: auto;   
   } 
#footer div {
 width:33%;   
}
.left {
text-align:center;
float:left;
}

.right{
float:right;
text-align:center;
}

.centered{
text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
```

As shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kLqZP/9/

Answer (score 1):

html

```
>   <div id="footer">
>         <p class="left">About<br />Contact<br />Next line here</p>
>         <p class="centered">Terms<br />Privacy<br />Disclaimer</p>
>         <p class="right"> does not evaluate or guarantee the accuracy</p>
>     
>     </div>
>     
>     css
>      #footer  {
>       color: #ffffff;
>       width:100%;
>       background: #111;
>       clear: both;
>       overflow: auto;   
>        } 
>     
>     .left {
>     text-align:left;
>     float:left;
>     }
>         .centered{
>     text-align:center;
>     float:left;  }
> 
>     .right{
>     float:left;
>     text-align:right;
>     }
```

just add float left in each column, then arrange the div. see if that works

Answer (score 0):

If you float your `<p>` they will take their width from their content, they won't have equal size. And BTW, maybe `div`s could be a better option for that task than `<p>`